# Неправильно рассчитывается стоимость звонка

Tags: javascript

Есть массив разговоров calls "представляет собой строку с датой и количеством проговоренных секунд".Первые 100 (сто) минут за один день оцениваются по 1 монете в минуту; Через 100 минут за один день каждая минута стоит 2 монеты в минуту; Все вызовы округляются до ближайшей минуты. Например, 59 сек ≈ 1 мин, 61 с ≈ 2 мин;

У меня ответ в итоге 502 а должно быть 106

```js
var calls = ["2014-02-05  60",
         "2014-02-05  60",
         "2014-02-05  60",
         "2014-02-05  6000"],///ответ должен быть 106
  data  = [],
  limit = 100,
  price = 0,
  priceOfDay = 0,
  thatDayDuration = 0,
  minutes, thatDayMinutes, duration, price;

calls.forEach(function(e){
  var tmp = e.split(" "); 
  data.push({'date' : tmp[0], 'duration' : tmp[1]});
})
data.forEach(function(el1,idx1){
  var out = false;
  data.forEach(function(el2,idx2){
    if(el1.date==el2.date && idx1!=idx2){  
      out = true;
      thatDayMinutes = Math.ceil(el2.duration/60);
    }  
  })
  if(out){
    thatDayDuration += thatDayMinutes;
    thatDayMinutes  =  (thatDayDuration > 100) ? ((thatDayDuration - 100)*2)+100 : thatDayDuration; 
    priceOfDay      =  thatDayMinutes;
  }else{
    duration =  Math.ceil(el1.duration/60);
    minutes  = (duration > 100) ? (duration-100)*2+100 : duration; 
    price    += minutes; 
  }
  total = price + priceOfDay; 
}) 
console.log(total)
```

Comment: Скажите, в чем смысл переменной out?

Comment: У Вас в условии противоречие. Если "все вызовы округляются до ближайшей минуты", то 61 сек должно округляться до 1 минуты, а не до двух, ибо 1 мин 1 сек гораздо ближе к 1 минуте, чем к 2 минутам.

Comment: @Yaant В пользу провайдера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первые 100 (сто) минут за один день оцениваются по 1 монете в минуту; Через 100 минут за один день каждая минута стоит 2 монеты в минуту

```js
const calls = [
  "2014-02-05  60", // 1 монета
  "2014-02-05  60", // 1 монета
  "2014-02-05  60", // 1 монета
  "2014-02-05  6000", // 97 монет + 6 монет
  "2014-02-06  6000", // 100 монет
  "2014-02-06  50",   // 2 монеты
]; // == 208 монет
const price = 1;   
const overLimitPrice = 2;
const limit = 100;

const aggregated = calls.reduce((aggregated, call) => {
  const [date, seconds] = call.split(/\s+/);
  const minutes = Math.ceil(seconds/60);
  aggregated[date] = minutes + (aggregated[date]||0);
  return aggregated;
}, {});

const total = Object.values(aggregated).map(minutes => {
  const overLimit = minutes - limit;
  return (overLimit>0) ? 
      overLimit * overLimitPrice  + limit * price:
      minutes * price;
}).reduce((sum, cost) => sum+cost, 0);

console.log(total);
```